# MOSS 2007 Event Receiver and Exchange Web Services API

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, exchange-server

My goal is to use Event Receiver to add Outlook Calendar Appointements when a ListItem is adding.

My Sharepoint Server is Moss 2007 and it is on a Win2008 R2.

I got and installed the Exchange Web Services API (32 bits) on the Sharepoint Server.

I created my Event Receiver, referenced the Exchanged Web Services API (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\1.2) and used it, put the Event Receiver DLL signed in the GAC and attached it to the concerned list.
When i add an item into that list,the Event Receiver is fired but then i have an error : "Impossible to load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The Specified file isn't found".

So, I put the ExchangeWebServices dll in the GAC, but where to reference it in my web.config (if it's the solution)?

Thanks for yours answers.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do that.

So, I put the EWS api dll in the GAC and then I referenced it in the web.config there :

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, &#xD;&#xA;Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </assemblies>
```

And now, I can reach it through my Event Receiver.